# Date not correctly displayed with JFreechart

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jfreechart

I am using JFreechart in Java to display a graph in my GUI. I loop through two dates and create an array of dates and numbers to display. The following code is what I use:

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(); 
cal.setTime(BeginDate); 

double Cumulative = 0.0;
TimeSeries DateTimes = new TimeSeries("DateTimes"); 

while (!cal.getTime().after(EndDate))
{
    Date d = cal.getTime(); 
    String Trade_Date = new SimpleDateFormat("d-M-y").format(d); 
    double Total = SQL_Sum("SQL Statement HERE"); 
    Cumulative = Cumulative + Total; 
    DateTimes.add(new Day(d), Cumulative);
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}

TimeSeriesCollection DataSeries = new TimeSeriesCollection(); 
DataSeries.addSeries(DateTimes); 
Chart.setDataset(DataSeries);
```

The result is:

[image: Graph]

The problem is that the dates are not shown as the need to be, namely in the d-m-y format. What is going wrong with this script?

Comment: Please show how you're setting up your chart. Ideally, show a [mcve] - and I'd *strongly* urge you to start following Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show the code, but your chart most likely has a `NumberAxis` for the x-axis.  If you change this to a `DateAxis` you will get formatted dates/times. And the API will let you control the formatting if you need to adjust it.

Comment: I'm using Netbeans with JFreechart components added to the Design Palette. The chart used in this example is a JLineChart. How can I link DateAxis to the Line chart?